# How to combine two vectors into pairs with separator

Tags: r, vector, paste

I hope I am using the correct terminology here.

I have two vectors,

```
 i_25_points <- 130:134
 j_25_points <- 65:69
```

I want to combine them into pairs, like a matrix almost but then collapse them down into a string like below

```
 130;65|130;66|130;67....134;65|134;66|134;67|134;68|134;69
```

How can I combine the? My original thought is to create the pairs by nested for loops and appending them together.

But there must be a more slick way to do so.

Comment: @Sotos awesome, that did it.

Comment: @Sotos I'm new to answering questions; is there a reason not to put that as an answer instead of a comment, so that it can be accepted? Literally a question to get to understand how people interact with SO.

Comment: @Benjamin I added it as answer. The reason i wrote it in comment section first is because I was searching for a duplicate question. Once I couldn't find one, I added it as answer

Comment: Aha! Thanks @Sotos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `outer` to create all the possible pairs, and simply `paste`, i.e.

```
paste(outer(x, y, paste, sep = ';'), collapse = '|')
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with expand.grid and paste

```
i_25_points <- 130:134
j_25_points <- 65:69
x <- expand.grid(j_25_points ,j_25_points )
paste(x[,1], x[,2], sep = ";", collapse = "|")
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `rep` and `paste`

```
paste(rep(i_25_points, each = length(j_25_points)),
      rep(j_25_points, length(i_25_points)), sep=";", collapse="|")
#[1] "130;65|130;66|130;67|130;68|130;69|131;65|131;66|131;67|131;68|131;69|132;65|132;66|132;67|132;68|132;69|133;65|133;66|133;67|133;68|133;69|134;65|134;66|134;67|134;68|134;69"
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
crossing(i_25_points, j_25_points) %>% 
   unite(newCol, i_25_points, j_25_points, sep=":") %>% 
   summarise(newCol = str_c(newCol, collapse="|")) %>%
   pull(newCol)
```

#### data

```
i_25_points <- c(130, 131, 132, 133, 134)
j_25_points <- 65:69
```